# Writing unique GUID to registry

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

What is the simplest way to write unique GUID to registry during each installation using WIX? I have a simple installer without custom actions dll and don't want to create one just for this task. I considered to use an embedded vbscript custom action but there are posts on the internet that discourage from doing that for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is this GUID being used for.  Does it have to be a GUID or does it just need to be unique?

Windows Installer doesn't have an ability to create a GUID without the use of a custom action. The "simplest" way depends on what programming language you are familiar with.  The most "robust" way is going to be with a C/C++ custom action.  In your custom action you set a property and then in a registry element you reference that [PROPERTY].

That said, if you can change the requirement, the simplest and even more robust way would be to use something like [Date][Time] to have a unique fingerprint with each install.

Comment: A useful [guide](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/events-and-actions/whats-not-in-the-book/) to implement a custom C++ action and an [example](https://github.com/rstropek/Samples/tree/master/WiXSamples/VisualStudioSnippetInstaller).